# SVN check sum error on commit

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, centos, centos6

before i used ubuntu 11.04 and everything go well with svn.
Two weeks ago, I switched to CentOS 6 and the problems appears.

this is svn infos :

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.15 (r1038135)
    compilé Mar 24 2011, 08:25:37

$ yum info subversion
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
Name       : subversion
Arch       : i686
Version    : 1.6.15
Release    : 0.1.el6.rfx
Size       : 21 M
Repo       : installed
From repo  : rpmforge-extras
Summary    : Modern Version Control System designed to replace CVS
URL        : http://subversion.tigris.org/
License    : BSD
```

error datails :

```
svn: Checksum mismatch for '/www/project/.svn/text-base/blah.ext'; 
expected: 'af3389a068d0747a549fc72fa5e6442c', actual: 'd60bf8195117a60415ff63e29813b8a2'
```

I have solved this probleme first time in few steps:

```
-copy and rename /www/project/blah.ext
-svn remove blah.ext
-svn ci -m ""
-rename blah.ext
-svn add blah.ext
-svn ci -m ""
```

But i can not do this all the time when I want to commit

Answer (score 0):

When you did this did you just copy your working directory over to the new machine or did you check the entire structure out?

If this is happening regularly, I would gather a diff of any work you have on this working copy, preserve it, obliterate the working copy, check it out anew, apply the patch of your diff and see how you're doing then.

Comment: This is comlicated :
In begin i have copy the directory -> not work  And then i have do a checkout and try to copy -> not work  
And then i modify file by file -> give me checksum mismatch -> not  work  
And i try the preview solution -> it works  

This have happen tow Times. At this time i have spent more one week with no commit.  
Thank you i will try to do that and i will give you result